# How reduce the canvas to display only a central portion of an image using fabric.js lib?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have big canvas of 500x500 with an image (originally 500x500) reduced to 300x200. It is working fine but I want to reduce the canvas so that only the central portion of the original image is displayed. Is this possible?

Current code.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas");
var img = new Image();  
img.onload=function(){
    var image = new fabric.Image(img,{name:"mainImage"});
    image.set({
        left:100,
        top: 100,
        angle: 0,
        padding:10,
        height:200,
        width:300,
        cornersize:10
    });
}
img.src = imageUrl;
canvas.add(image);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check these functions: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#centerObject
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#centerObjectH
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#centerObjectV

Comment: ptCoder your link suggestion work for position of object, but  need to display   image of center portion inside object(300 x 200) my original image size is Original Size: 500 x 500. i want to 300 x 200 resolution from original image with center part.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can center your image with `canvas.centerObject()` function.

**Example:**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

var src = "http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg";

fabric.Image.fromURL(src, function(oImg) {
    oImg.set({
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
    });
    canvas.add(oImg);
    canvas.centerObject(oImg);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ckqk2Lzs/8/

I hope this help.

Comment: thanks for replay, But i need to  show center portion of image because my image size in 500px X 500px i need to set that in in 300px X 200px.

Comment: You need to crop your image?

Comment: yes something like that but other image part not remove from object just hide an maintain better resolution. This application used this type of during the resize functionality http://www.photocollage.net/collage/